# I'm doing a do while loop where it asks user to input ID,but it will always show the error message after one loop before user enters anything

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I want to user to enter menu ID

```
do {        
    id = "";
    System.out.print("Enter Menu ID : ");
    id = sc.nextLine();
    correctInput = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < menu.length; i++){
        if ((id.toUpperCase()).equals(menu[i].getMenuID()) {
        correctInput = true;
        //codes that comparing the user entered **ID** with **ID** in the array
        //and get the quantity that user entered and calculate the total price
    }
    if (correctInput == false)
        System.out.println("\nInvalid ID, please enter again!\n");
} while (correctInput == false);
//codes that ask user whether to add-on
```

When user wants to repeat to make order, it will always show the error message before user enters anything

> Add-on? (Y/N) : y
>
> Enter Menu ID :
>
> Invalid ID, please enter again!
>
> Enter Menu ID :

Can I know what is wrong with my code?

Comment: Could you change `//codes` to your code - so we can reproduce the issue?

Comment: correctInput where is initialized? And, more important, where is your logic that assigns a new value to correctInput?

Comment: Again, you've included some code, but there's nothing here that will set `correctInput == true`. So if you're asking me for help, from what I've been given, your issue is that your program will loop infinitely.

Comment: **I should be able to copy and paste your code and have the same issue you are having**. [reprex]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the input/output snippet you shared, it seems that `id = sc.nextLine()` isn't waiting for user input. This could happen if you still have input queued - e.g., you read the "Y" for "Add-on? (Y/N)" with [`next()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next()) but didn't handle the newline following the "Y". You could handle it by having another `nextLine()` **before** the `while` loop, and just ignore the result:

```
// Get rid of the queued newline character - return value can be ignored
sc.nextLine();

// Start the loop for reading the id:
do {  
    // code...
```

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is compare the string values without worrying about case sensitivity.

```
 if (id.equalsIgnoreCase(menu[i].getMenuID())){
    correctInput = true;
    // your code
 }
```